# Using callback from Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate changes managed array argument

Tags: c#, arrays, c++-cli

Here is my unmanaged code:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(array<int>^% arguments);
typedef void (__stdcall *MyCallback)(array<int>^% arguments);

void Test(MyDelegate^ delegate)
{
    MyCallback myCallback = static_cast<MyCallback>(Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegate).ToPointer());

    array<int>^ foo = gcnew array<int>(5);
    foo[0] = 1;
    foo[1] = 2;
    foo[2] = 3;
    foo[3] = 4;
    foo[4] = 5;

    myCallback(foo);
}
```

result:

The delegate is called, but array.Length of the argument in delegate is one instead of five.  The first element in the array is correct.  After the callback foo.Length() is also one!  Can anyone tell me why??

More infomation:

I am using C++/CLI to wrap a C++ library so that it can be accessed by C#.  The C++ library uses member function pointers ([FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible)) to achieve a type of unmanaged "delegate".  I need to provide one of these "FastDelegate" member function pointers that eventually calls a c# delegate.  To achieve this it seems I need to do one of the following:

- Store a delegate reference in an unmanaged (non ref) class.
- Get the address of a managed class to pass to an unmanaged class.  (So that I can use a member function pointer to it.)
- Something else?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is not very clear; you only told us that your code doesn't work, but not what your code is supposed to do. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: And all of your code seems to be managed. I see no unmanaged code. What's the purpose of the GetFunctionPointerForDelegate call?

Comment: This is a double thunk, going from managed to unmanaged and back to managed.  What you can't see is the intermediary, the managed array getting converted to an int**.  A unmanaged type that could be an array but also simply a pointer to a pointer to a single int.  The pinvoke marshaller cannot possibly guess at an array size so can punt for one element.  Avoid double thunks, there was no point to using Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().

Comment: @Hans-you answered my question, Thanks!

Comment: @dtb-you are correct in that my question is answered but I still have a problem to solve.